# One-hot encode columns where values are data.frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have a `tibble` where rows have *lists* of dataframes of values for each column e.g.

```r
library(tibble)

df = tibble(age = list(data.frame(21), data.frame(57), NULL, data.frame(36)),
            role = list(data.frame('scavenger', 'cleaner'), data.frame('cleaner'), NULL, data.frame('cleaner', 'scavenger', 'hunter')),  
            planet = list(data.frame('jupiter'), data.frame('earth'), data.frame('mars'), data.frame('mars')))
```

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  age              role             planet          
  <list>           <list>           <list>          
1 <df[,1] [1 × 1]> <df[,2] [1 × 2]> <df[,1] [1 × 1]>
2 <df[,1] [1 × 1]> <df[,1] [1 × 1]> <df[,1] [1 × 1]>
3 <NULL>           <NULL>           <df[,1] [1 × 1]>
4 <df[,1] [1 × 1]> <df[,3] [1 × 3]> <df[,1] [1 × 1]>
```

I wish to one-hot encode columns which have rows where the dataframe is of size `1 x n` (n > 1) i.e. columns where some rows have multiple values (e.g. the `role` column is replaced by multiple one-hot-encoded columns `scavenger`, `cleaner`, `hunter`), and additionally where they are of size `1 x 1` replace the cell with the single value in the dataframe:

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 5
    age scavenger    cleaner    hunter    planet 
  <dbl> <bool>       <bool>     <bool>    <chr>  
1    21 1            1          0         jupiter
2    57 0            1          0         earth  
3    NA <NA>         <NA>       <NA>      mars   
4    36 1            1          1         mars
```

If columns with only one value per row were not dataframes, I could just use `tidyr`'s [`unnest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933256/how-to-convert-a-list-column-to-a-vector-in-a-tibble-in-r) function, but unfortunately this will e.g. create distinct columns for each `age` (undesired).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function which achieves this.

```r
library(functional)
library(tidyr)

# A few helper functions
null_to_na <- function(a) {a[sapply(a, function(x) length(x)==0L)] <- NA
    a}

null_to_dfna <- function(a) {a[sapply(a, function(x) length(x)==0L)] <- data.frame(NA)
    a}

col_has_multiple_vals <- function(a) {NROW(unlist(null_to_na(a))) > NROW(a)}
```

```r
# Main function
unnest_plus <- function(df) {
    condition = sapply(df, col_has_multiple_vals)

    multi_cols = which(condition)
    singl_cols = which(!condition)

    # Convert 1x1 df col entries to their values
    df[singl_cols] = lapply(df[singl_cols], function(x) unlist(null_to_na(x)))

    # unnest will drop rows with NULL values, so clean them first
    df[multi_cols] = lapply(df[multi_cols], function(x) null_to_dfna(x))

    # unnest / one-hot encode cols with multiple vals per cell
    df = unnest(df, cols=all_of(multi_cols))

    # drop old cols due to unnest behaving weirdly with NA's
    df = df[!(names(df) %in% names(condition[multi_cols]))]

    df
}
```

```r
>>> unnest_plus(df)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
    age X.scavenger. X.cleaner. X.hunter. planet 
  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  
1    21 scavenger    cleaner    <NA>      jupiter
2    57 <NA>         cleaner    <NA>      earth  
3    NA <NA>         <NA>       <NA>      mars   
4    36 scavenger    cleaner    hunter    mars
```

**Note:** `unnest` does not distinguish between `NA`s and missing values (i.e. desired `0`) when creating dummy variables.